# Why do I have 2 documents folder in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, folder-redirection, files-folders

I have two asynchronous documents folder in Windows 11.

One `C:\users\jakob\Documents` with my documents from OneDrive (this is the one t"Documents" in the explorer menu to the left links to) and one `C:\users\jakob\OneDrive\Dokumente` (German Windows installation) which is empty

Is this the right way if I want my documents to be synchronized with OneDrive?

Or is this just an artefact of the installation trying to restore some old installation?

Will this lead to problems?

Is it possible to have only one of these folders and to synchronize it to OneDrive?

How would the folder structure look like after a fresh clean install of English Windows 11 with Documents synchronized with OneDrive?

I have read

> ```
> Open File Explorer
> Click This PC
> Right-click on Documents
> Click Properties
> Click Location
> Click Restore Default
> Click Apply
> Click OK
> ```

on https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/why-do-i-have-two-documents-folders.584567/. Should I only follow this instruction if I do not want my documents to be in the OneDrive Cloud or should I always follow them to have a tidier folder structure? I would like to decide now before I copy all my data from an external disk to one of these two folders.

Comment: OneDrive supports backing up your Desktop and Documents folder, by doing that, the folders are moved into your OneDrive folder. This can be disabled from within OneDrive. Once disabled the folders should be moved to their original location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are syncing documents between your local machine and One Drive (I want my documents to be synchronized with OneDrive?) then you will have both a One Drive folder and a Local folder.

This is completely normal (I see this on my Windows 11 and Windows 10 machines). A fresh install of Windows 11 will not change this.

It appears to me that all is well.

If you want documents not sync'd to One Drive, use a completely different folder for them (C:\Other_Documents); or, set them up in Documents and turn One Drive Sync OFF for this folder.  Check first by testing.

Your actual folder structure is a personal choice. I have documents in Documents and documents elsewhere. Nothing whatever goes to One Drive that I do not want there.

Remember that One Drive wants to own your documents, so go very carefully and test. Nothing is wrong - you just need to exercise care.

Comment: Before my disk crashed I always had a separate partition for my data where I had full control over my folder structure. But now that I want to sync all my data with OneDrive I cannot use a separate partition. Do you think Microsoft messed less with my folder structure when I put my data into a new folder `C:\users\jakob\OneDrive\data` or just into `C:\users\jakob\OneDrive\Dokumente`? Both ways I could use OneDrive version control in the cloud?

Comment: I keep my local files and One Drive files in the same partition. I think Microsoft just assumes one partition.

Comment: I want all my files on OneDrive. I am just have not decided into which OneDrive folder I should copy my old data partition.

Comment: I just keep One Drive and Local files (which are sync'd) in the same partition for ease of use.

Comment: If I put all my data inlcuding images and videos into ` C:\users\jakob\OneDrive\Dokumente`, does Microsoft somehow mess with it, like moving the images into some "Picture" folder? If I create a ne folder ` C:\users\jakob\OneDrive\data` for my data then I still have all the link in the file explorer pointing to ` C:\users\jakob\OneDrive\Dokumente` which I would not use anyway in the second case. If I have data that I do not want to have in the could I can use  `C:\users\jakob\Documents`, but this is independent of which folder I should use for OneDrive.

Comment: Where I have used One Drive, it will normally use the same folder structure as I set locally (but I do have local Picture and Video folders).  So it would be worth your while to organize things properly. That has helped me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139435/discussion-between-jakob-and-john).